# Android - YouTubePlayer Play Live

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I am using [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/) to do a project about youtube live.

```
public class YoutubeLiveActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

private Context mContext = this;
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment;
private YouTubePlayer player;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube_live);

    youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);
    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, this);

}


private void playVideoAtSelection() {
    if (!(player == null)) {
        player.loadVideo(LIVE_ID);
    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer arg1, boolean arg2) {
    this.player = arg1;

    playVideoAtSelection();

}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {

}

}
```

YouTubePlayer cannot play the live and display "An error occurred Tap to retry". However, it can play a normal video. Please help!!

********** Updated **********

I found the problem about cannot play live video on YouTubePlayer. It is because the youtube version of mobile is not the latest version. Once updated the youtube on play store, the live video can play normally.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Use the Youtube player. 

public class YouTubePlayerActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
    public String videoId = "";
    private YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPaused() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlaying() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
        }
    };
    private YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdStarted() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoading() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoEnded() {
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoStarted() {
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_you_tube_player);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            videoId = bundle.getString(CommonUtils.INTENT_YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID);
        }

        YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(CommonUtils.You_Tube_Api_Key, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error: Fail to Initialize!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
        player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo(videoId);
        }
    }
}

activity_you_tube_player.xml 

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000"
        android:padding="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>



Download Youtube jar File From this link, and Copy it into libs folder
[https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/][1]
```